# Эфес или Ефес? Какой вариант выбрать?

Tags: грамотная-речь, орфография

Встречаются два варианта, "Эфес" - чаще.

Откуда взялось вариантное написание и какой вариант предпочтительнее (если контекст исторический - описываются жития святых)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Ефес* - устаревшая форма современного *эфеса*.

*Ефес* фиксируется словарями Даля и Ушакова, но с параллельной формой *эфес*.

[ЕФЕ́С](http://www.classes.ru/all-russian/russian-dictionary-Ushakov-term-14885.htm), эфе́с м. нем. ручка, рукоятка, хватка у шпаги, сабли, у палаша. *Ефе́сный,* к ефесу относящ.

**[Этимология](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%8D%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%81)**

> Происходит от нем. Gefäß «сосуд; эфес», от fassen «хватать». Русск.
> эфес (также ефе́с, стар. гефе́с — в Уст. морск. (1720 г.).

В житиях святых ориентируйтесь на общую стилистику, специально "старить" слово не надо.

Comment: См. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AD%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%81_%28%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%29

Comment: В Вики два Эфеса: греч. Ἔφεσος и нем. Gefäß.

Comment: Но речь-то в вопросе, скорее всего, идёт о городе с названием Эфес, а не о рукоятке шпаги, сабли или палаша.

Comment: Слава, согласна. Пусть автор вопроса разбирается! )))